# List specific with a single table

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have following messages table:

[image]

I want to list all messages in a inbox like for example,
lets assume I am user number 1 so my inbox should show
me following:

Messages with user 2
Messages with user 3
Messages with user 4

What is the best way to build a query for this?

I've came up with somewhat weird query that looks like: (pseudo code)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `message`
WHERE
    (`user_id_sender` = 1 AND `user_id_receiver` NOT 1)
    OR
    (`user_id_sender` NOT 1 AND `user_id_receiver` = 1)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That's very simple

```
SELECT user_id_sender ID,
       (SELECT user_id_reciever 
        FROM messages 
        WHERE user_id_sender NOT IN(ID) 
        GROUP BY user_id_reciever
       )
FROM message
```